# Spam flag indicator on flag history page doesn't look right

Tags: bug, design, flag-history

On [my flag history page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1849664), spam flags don't look right; they're aligned too tightly with the "helpful" text:

> [image]

Comment: *beats @Undo with a giant block of whitespace*

Comment: ...and a giant font for question titles. Even question list does not have so strong titles.

Comment: Sorry but this was already reported  you missed out @undo

Comment: @bluefeet Ah, yep. I saw that post, missed that it covered spam flags too. Thanks!